# When calculating DOS and band structures, do I still need to provide a regular mesh for MetaGGA functionals as in the case with hybrid functionals?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, band-structure, density-of-states, functional

In VASP manual it is mentioned that the deorbitalized versions of SCAN and R2SCAN MetaGGA functionals do not depend on the kinetic energy density but instead on the Laplacian of the charge density.

When calculating DOS and band structures, do I still need to provide a regular mesh in SCF calculation as in the case with hybrid functionals unlike fixing the charge density in NSCF calculation for PBE functionals?

In other words, should I perform a SCF calculation to calculate the DOS unlike PBE functionals (where I simply need to fix the charge density) in a nscf run. In metaGGAs that compute the kinetic energy density I have to provide the regular mesh in addition to zero weight K points for band calculations. So for functionals like "R2SCAN-L" should the charge density be fixed ?

Comment: No matter which functional is used, DOS and band structure are always computed by sampling the reciprocal space.

Comment: I was not clear (modified it) in my question, apologies. I meant to ask if I should perform a SCF calculation to calculate the DOS unlike PBE functionals where I simply need to fix the charge density in a nscf run.
In metaGGAs that compute the kinetic energy density I have to provide the regular mesh in addition to zero weight K points for band calculations. So for functionals like "R2SCAN-L" should the charge density be fixed ?